# Create a pivot table depending of two dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have an Excel table with statistics on issues handled by my team:

```
|Date opened|Date closed|Description|...|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|---|
|2020-03-05 |2020-04-23 |   foo     |...|
|2020-04-30 |           |   bar     |...|
```

I would like to have a dashboard reporting, at the end of each month, the average 'age' of opened issues.

The pivot table I am trying to build would read, as of today (May 27th):

```
March 31st - 26d
April 30th - 0d
May 27th - 28d
```

I have been fiddling with the Pivot Table wizard, but I have not been able to pull this off, and I must use the wrong keywords to describe what I am trying to do, because Google is not my friend on this one.

Comment: What I can confirm is that the PivotTable does not perform additional calculations of the data in the source data. I think you should create a secondary column. The time difference between the source data and the current date (or month-end) will not calculated by the wizard in the PivotTable.

Comment: Hi Jean, PivotTable can do the `average 'age' of opened issues` for you. But a calculation of `Age of Opened issues` itself has to be available in the Data Source for the PivotTable to calculate the average.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the source data into a Table (Ctrl+T) then renamed the table case_data.

Then I added a column called "Days open" with this formula:

```
=DAYS(IF([@[Date closed]]<>"",[@[Date closed]],TODAY()),[@[Date opened]])
```

If you want business days open, use [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) and consider passing a list of holidays into the function.

[image]

After doing that, I realised I didn't need to, but left it because hey, why not?

To get the number of open cases on any given day and the SUM of total days open (in case of overlapping case periods), I created a new table with one row for each day in the year:

[image]

If it's of interest, you can get a list of dates between two dates using the SEQUENCE function. This is useful for adjusting to leap years. This is the formula in cell G2:

```
=DATE($F$2,1,SEQUENCE(DAYS(DATE($F$2,12,31),DATE($F$2,1,1))+1))
```

The Year in question is in cell F2.

To calculate the total number of open cases on any given day, we just check whether the day in question is between the open and closed date. To do this, we can test if the date is greater than the date opened and return a 1 if it is, or a zero if it isn't (using the -- operator), then do the same to check if the date is less than or equal to the date closed (or today if the case is still open), then take the SUM of the product of those two arrays.

To put it another way, if the date is both after the opened date and less than or equal to the closed date (or today if still open), then return a 1. Take the SUM over all the cases to count how many cases were open on that day.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(G2>case_data[Date opened]),--(G2<=IF(case_data[Date closed]="",TODAY(),case_data[Date closed])))
```

Finally, to calculate the number of case-days open, use this:

```
=IF(H2=0,0,I1+H2)
```

This is saying, if today's value for open cases is zero, then days open should also be zero. If it's not zero, then days open should be the sum of todays open cases plus the days open value from the previous day.

So, the first day after the first case opens (i.e. March 6th), open cases is 1 and days open is 1. For all the days between the date opened and date closed, cases open is 1 and the days open iterates until cases open is zero again. i.e.:

[image]

Then:

[image]

To refer back to your question, if we filter the table on the dates you specified:

[image]

It should be 27 days open between April 30 and May 27, not 28 (assuming you are not counting the date opened as the first day).

To get avg days open on any given date, we need to consider situations where there are more than one case open on the same day. So, I added some more dummy data:

[image]

You can see that it's changed the "open cases" column in March:

[image]

I've added "avg days open" with this formula:

```
=IFERROR(I2/H2,0)
```

On the 6th of March, there was one case open. So the days open was 1. On the 8th of March, there were 2 cases open. One of thoses cases had been open for 3 days and one had been open for 1 day. So the total days open for the 8th of March was 4 and the avg days open was 4 / 2 = 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following steps,

1. Create a new column in the source data like Age of Open issues (Days)

   *I have created the data source as a table with some random date values and have calculated the ‘Age of Open issues (Days)’ as below,*

   [image: data_source_AgeOfOpenIssues]

   You can see that for the Age calculation I’ve used today’s date as a reference.
2. Then add a PivotTable
   ***(In my example, I’ve added it to a new worksheet)***
3. In the Field List pane, please add the data source fields (by checking the item or by drag and drop) to below specified ‘Areas’ of the Pivot table,

   **Field List Item > AREA**

   **i. Opened >   ROWS**

   **ii.**  (Drag and Drop) **Opened    > VALUES** *(We will use this to Count no. of Open issues)*

   **iii.  Closed > FILTERS**

   **iv.   Age of Open issues (Days) > VALUES**

   Initially, the PivotTable would look something like the below,

   [image: PivotTable_Initial]
4. In the filter field **Closed** (Row 1), check ‘Select Multiple Items’,
   uncheck ‘All’, finally check **(blank)**

   Now your Pivot is set to filter in and shows only *Open issues*.
5. In the Row Labels column which is listing the **Opened** dates the data is already grouped for me in *Months* instead of the individual dates

   If it shows individual dates for you, then,

   Right-click on one of the cells in the ‘Row Labels’ column **>** Group **>** Choose ‘Months’

   *You can deselect the other items by clicking on each of them one after the other*

   *You can additionally choose grouping by ‘Years’ when your data source includes dates from multiple years*
6. Next, Right Click on one of the cells in the ‘Sum of Age of Open issues (Days)’ column **>** Value Field Settings **>** Under ‘Summarize value field by’ section choose **Average**
7. Further down, you can adjust the decimal places on the resulting Averages. Click ‘Number Format’ button **>**  Category: Number **>** Adjust decimal places as desired

   After applying steps from 4 through 7 you should see a PivotTable like the below,

   [image: PivotTable_Final]

Hope this helps!